# Advanced Security Audit Policy Not Applying To Win7

Tags: group-policy

Issue

I am trying to apply a GPO with Advanced Security Audit Policy configurations to a Windows 7 client but the setting are not applying.

I double-checked my work using this article - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd408940(v=ws.10).aspx

I did enable Audit: Force audit policy subcategory settings (Windows Vista or later) to override audit policy category settings

When I run auditpol.exe /get /category:* I see that only the default advanced audit settings are applied, not the ones I set in the new GPO. I know that the GPO itself is applying to the computer because other settings in the GPO are present and RSOP shows the GPO applied successfully.

We have a GPO higher in the OU structure that applies some advanced audit settings so I thought that for some reason it was interfering or overridding but they are also not showing in auditpol.exe /get /category:*. I performed a auditpol.exe /clear which clears the policy

|
|

After auditpol.exe /clear

|

Category/Subcategory                      Setting

System

Security System Extension               No Auditing

System Integrity                        No Auditing

IPsec Driver                            No Auditing

Other System Events                     No Auditing

Security State Change                   No Auditing

Logon/Logoff

Logon                                   No Auditing

Logoff                                  No Auditing

Account Lockout                         No Auditing

IPsec Main Mode                         No Auditing

IPsec Quick Mode                        No Auditing

IPsec Extended Mode                     No Auditing

Special Logon                           No Auditing

Other Logon/Logoff Events               No Auditing

Network Policy Server                   No Auditing

Object Access

File System                             No Auditing

Registry                                No Auditing

Kernel Object                           No Auditing

SAM                                     No Auditing

Certification Services                  No Auditing

Application Generated                   No Auditing

Handle Manipulation                     No Auditing

File Share                              No Auditing

Filtering Platform Packet Drop          No Auditing

Filtering Platform Connection           No Auditing

Other Object Access Events              No Auditing

Detailed File Share                     No Auditing

Privilege Use

Sensitive Privilege Use                 No Auditing

Non Sensitive Privilege Use             No Auditing

Other Privilege Use Events              No Auditing

Detailed Tracking

Process Termination                     No Auditing

DPAPI Activity                          No Auditing

RPC Events                              No Auditing

Process Creation                        No Auditing

Policy Change

Audit Policy Change                     No Auditing

Authentication Policy Change            No Auditing

Authorization Policy Change             No Auditing

MPSSVC Rule-Level Policy Change         No Auditing

Filtering Platform Policy Change        No Auditing

Other Policy Change Events              No Auditing

Account Management

User Account Management                 No Auditing

Computer Account Management             No Auditing

Security Group Management               No Auditing

Distribution Group Management           No Auditing

Application Group Management            No Auditing

Other Account Management Events         No Auditing

DS Access
  Directory Service Changes               No Auditing

Directory Service Replication           No Auditing

Detailed Directory Service Replication  No Auditing

Directory Service Access                No Auditing

Account Logon

Kerberos Service Ticket Operations      No Auditing

Other Account Logon Events              No Auditing

Kerberos Authentication Service         No Auditing

Credential Validation                   No Auditing

I then performed a gpupdate /force and rebooted but AuditPol still shows 'no auditing' for all settings.

I also deleted the audit.csv file, which appears to contain the settings of the GPO higher in the structure (even though I read that is only contains local settings) but not the new GPO, in C:\Windows\security\audit and then performed a gpupdate /force. After running gpupdate /force, the file was reinstated and it showed the default settings and the advanced audit settings from the GPO higher in the OU structure, not the new GPO settings, but auditpol was still showing no auditing for all settings. Also, the audit.csv file modify date was from months ago so I suspect is it just pulling the informed from the initial GPO? I tried enforcing and ranking the new GPO higher but it still does not apply.

Environment

windows 7 SP1 client and Windows 2008R2 DC

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows 7 / Vista:, run start > `cmd.exe`.

To list the options:

```
c:\auditpol /list /subcategory:*
```

Category/Subcategory

***System***

- Security State Change
- Security System Extension
- System Integrity
- IPsec Driver
- Other System Events

***Logon/Logoff***

- Logon
- Logoff
- Account Lockout
- IPsec Main Mode
- IPsec Quick Mode
- IPsec Extended Mode
- Special Logon
- Other Logon/Logoff Events
- Network Policy Server

***Object Access***

- File System
- Registry
- Kernel Object
- SAM
- Certification Services
- Application Generated
- Handle Manipulation
- File Share
- Filtering Platform Packet Drop
- Filtering Platform Connection
- Other Object Access Events
- Detailed File Share

***Privilege Use***

- Sensitive Privilege Use
- Non Sensitive Privilege Use
- Other Privilege Use Events

***Detailed Tracking***

- Process Creation
- Process Termination
- DPAPI Activity
- RPC Events

***Policy Change***

- Audit Policy Change
- Authentication Policy Change
- Authorization Policy Change
- MPSSVC Rule-Level Policy Change
- Filtering Platform Policy Change
- Other Policy Change Events

***Account Management***

- User Account Management
- Computer Account Management
- Security Group Management
- Distribution Group Management
- Application Group Management
- Other Account Management Events

***DS Access***

- Directory Service Access
- Directory Service Changes
- Directory Service Replication
- Detailed Directory Service Replication

***Account Logon***

- Credential Validation
- Kerberos Service Ticket Operations
- Other Account Logon Events
- Kerberos Authentication Service

Then use `auditpol /set ...` to set value. For more help, use `auditpol /?`.